# ubuntu python cron job stops without error

Tags: python, django, cron

I have an amazon instance that is running my site. I recently tried to set up a cron job and it just stops without throwing any error or anything halfway through the task.

`crontab -l` shows

```
30 13 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6 /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/testprep/bin/python /home/ubuntu/web/testprep/manage.py daily > /tmp/prepcron.log
```

Here is my python/django script:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("starting")
        date = datetime.now().date()
        print("date is", date)
        try:
            users = User.objects.filter(test="ACT", state__in=[User.WAITING, User.READY, User.SOLUTION])
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e)) 
        print("number of users", users.count())
        ...
```

And at 13:30 I get this in my logfile:

```
starting
date is 2016-07-19
```

And that's it! No error is thrown or caught. `Number of users` is never printed. The program just gives up halfway through. If I run that command by hand (literal copy and paste) then the script executes as expected, this only happens when I try to schedule it.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Is the program still being ran? Did it get hung on the filter? That would be the only reason I can think of to not only not throw the exception, but also not print the number of users.

Comment: If it's still running it's been running for several hours now. How would I check for that?

Comment: do a `ps aux | grep "SCRIPTNAME"` edit: SCRIPTNAME should be (from  your command) manage.py, so `ps aux | grep "manage.py"`

Comment: `ubuntu   21833  0.0  0.0  10460   948 pts/0    S+   19:29   0:00 grep --color=auto manage.py` what does that mean?

Comment: if you notice, the command ends in "grep --color auto manage.py", which means the search result you got is a result of the process listing. If that was your only output from the process list, it is not still hung.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the issue was actually in my django `settings.py` file. The database was just an `sqlite` database with a relative path. Apparently when running the code from a cron job, it needs an absolute path. So changing the code to this fixed the issue:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'database'),
    }
}
```